# converting circular string to json

Tags: node.js

in following snippet i want to json the resonse but it is giving `Type error`.

```
export class FileRoutes {
  public static async upload(req, res: express.Response, next) {
    try {
      const file = req.files.file;
      const response = await fileService.uploadToS3(file);
      await res.json(response);
      res.sendStatus(status.OK);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  }
}
```

i am getting typeError i want to json my response

```
 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Request'
    |     property 'response' -> object with constructor 'Response'
    --- property 'request' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (C:\Users\jains\OneDrive\Desktop\realiize\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\jains\OneDrive\Desktop\realiize\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at C:\Users\jains\OneDrive\Desktop\realiize\server\lib\routes\file\routes.js:56:50
    at step (C:\Users\jains\OneDrive\Desktop\realiize\server\lib\routes\file\routes.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\jains\OneDrive\Desktop\realiize\server\lib\routes\file\routes.js:14:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\jains\OneDrive\Desktop\realiize\server\lib\routes\file\routes.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

this is a part of response which i am getting

```
[![this is screenshot of response][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0z6T.png
```

Comment: can you somehow debug and add content of `response` here ?

Comment: i have added screenshot

Comment: Do you need all the properties. Can you delete the one that's causing the circular reference and keep the rest?

Comment: its a response after uploading to s3 bucket, i don`t think we can delete the property which is causing error